# Compile MySQL 5.6.30 on CentOS 6.7 - "Manually-specified variables were not used"

Tags: mysql, variables, compilation, cmake

I have downloaded the mysql-5.6.30.tar.gz source file, extracted and I'm using the following CMAKE command:

```
cmake /mysql-5.6.30 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql -DWITH_CHARSET=CP1251=1 
-DENABLE_THREAD_SAFE_CLIENT=1 -DMAX_INDEXES=250 -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 
-DWITH_BOOST=%HOME/mysqlboost -DENABLE_DOWNLOADS=1
```

Most of that is normal, apart from the MAX_INDEXES value of 250. The client has very specific requirements for this, and is the reason I am trying to compile this from source (there doesn't appear to be a way to change this value once MySQL is installed, must be done at compile).

CMake runs through the compilation (after i fixed various dependencies being missing and such), but at the end states:

```
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
    CMAKE_CC_COMPILER
    DOWNLOAD_BOOST
    ENABLE_THREAD_SAFE_CLIENT
    MAX_INDEXES
    WITH_BOOST
    WITH_CHARSET
-- Build files have been written to: /mysql-5.6.30
```

This is a bit of an issue, as I specifically needed MAX_INDEXES to be written to the build files so I can install MySQL with it. Can anyone tell me A) Why is it ignoring every single variable I passed to it? and/or B) Is there any other way to enforce MAX_INDEXES (to at least 200) in a MySQL Installation. If it helps, it can be 5.6 or 5.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the MAX_INDEXES and ENABLE_THREAD_SAFE_CLIENT problem with this from the MySQL source directory (tested):

```
MY_FLAGS="DMAX_INDEXES=256 -DENABLE_THREAD_SAFE_CLIENT"
cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$MY_FLAGS" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$MY_FLAGS" .
```

The reason it ignored your variables was because they were not Cmake variables, but rather macros referenced by the source of MySQL (some).

The variables understood by Cmake are documented at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-configuration-options.html

For the internal macros you have to search in the MySQL source.

Answer (score 0):

According to mysql documentation on [source configuration options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-configuration-options.html), the configuration options you listed are eithes supported from a certain mysql v5.7 version or are not even listed on that page, meaning they are not mysql specific.

Compile a mysql v5.7.1 or higher from source to be able to set max_indexes config option.